# Adding Content To Custom Widget Class Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having difficulty generating the content I want to display on my card widget in Flutter. I've commented out the code with the styling I'm trying to achieve. However, even when I try just adding a `Text('Test Text')` widget to my ReusableCard class, it doesn't emulate. I don't see any errors, and I don't understand why nothing is popping up. I tried using a Stack widget with no luck.

This is a companion project for the Flutter App Development Bootcamp.
I'll share my GitHub repo link here: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/coletoncodes/bmi-calculator)

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i saw your code you must return the widget int reuseale class

Your code

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.color, this.cardChild});

  final Color color;
  final Widget cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
     //you have missed this line
      child:cardChild
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you forgot add child for ReusableCard here.

```
Expanded(
                child: ReusableCard(
                  color: primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ReusableCard(color: primaryColor),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ReusableCard(color: primaryColor),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ReusableCard(color: primaryColor),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Add your child or add empty container for that

```
ReusableCard(
                  color: primaryColor,
                  cardChild: Container(
                  )
)
```